# How to merge two Audio Units into AudioBufferList for AURenderCallback

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-audio, audiounit, avkit

Please see code below. All I want to, is to merge bufflist1 and bufflist2, then inset to ioData. But I don't know how.

```
OSStatus PlayCallback(void *inRefCon,
                        AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags,
                        const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp,
                        UInt32 inBusNumber,
                        UInt32 inNumberFrames,
                        AudioBufferList *ioData) {
    ALNPlayer *player = (__bridge ALNPlayer *)inRefCon;
    
    OSStatus status;
    
    player->buffList->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = CONST_BUFFER_SIZEV3;
    //read audio1 data to bufflist1
    status = AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer(player->audioConverter1, lyInInputDataProcV1, inRefCon, &inNumberFrames, player->buffList1, NULL);
    
    //read audio2 data to bufflist2
    status = AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer(player->audioConverter2, lyInInputDataProcV2, inRefCon, &inNumberFrames, player->buffList2, NULL);
    

    //below is copy bufferlist1 to ioData
    //and now i want to merge bufflist1 and buflist2,then inset to iodata. But I don't know how.
    memcpy(ioData->mBuffers[0].mData, player->buffList->mBuffers[0].mData, player->buffList->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize);
    

}
```

Comment: Could you define what you mean by merge?

Comment: @sbooth thanks for replying. I want to play two file at the same time.  Or should I use two audiounits to play?

Comment: There are multiple ways to handle this. Since you're using the C API an option is to use a multi-channel mixer (`kAudioUnitSubType_MultiChannelMixer`) with an input channel for each file (each with a corresponding input callback) and your play callback would get its input from the mixer's output channel.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I would have a try.